# Efficiently determine if any rows satisfy a predicate in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists

I'd like to query the database as to whether or not one or more rows exist that satisfy a given predicate. However, I am not interested in the distinction between there being one such row, two rows or a million - just if there are 'zero' or 'one or more'. And I do not want Postgres to waste time producing an exact count that I do not need.

In DB2, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM REAL_TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUE')
```

and then checking if zero rows or one row was returned from the query.

But Postgres has no dummy table available, so what is the best option?

If I create a one-row dummy table myself and use that in place of SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1, will the query optimizer be smart enough to not actually read that table when running the query, and otherwise 'do the right thing'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have a dummy table because you don't need one.

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM REAL_TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUE')
```

Alternatively if you want a true/false answer:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM REAL_TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUE')
```

Comment: Intriguing, especially the second one. It does return the expected results. I have not been able to test for efficiency since no real production data as of yet exists in these Postgres tables, but the syntax is so simple that the query optimizer should not be able to get it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

How about just doing this?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM REAL_TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'VALUE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

`1` means there is a value. `0` means no value.

This will always return one row.

Comment: This will not always return one row, it will return an error if the subquery matches more than one row.

Comment: Thanks to Gordon Linoff for the suggestion, however I get the error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" in the case where the table has more than one row that satisfies the predicate, which to me indicates that Postgres does not stop processing the query after the first row is found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with "no row" if no row matches, you can even just:

```
SELECT 1 FROM real_table WHERE column = 'VALUE' LIMIT 1;
```

Performance is basically the same as with `EXISTS`. Key to performance for big tables is a matching index.